# When is a StreamContext reusable ? And when should it not be reused?

Tags: php, stream

I'm passing from http to https, and therefore I have to add a `StreamContext` to several `read_file` and `get_file_contents` calls.

I need to replace

```
read_file('http://'.$host.$uri);
```

by

```
$stream_context = stream_context_create([
    /* some lenghty options array */
]);
read_file('https://'.$host.$uri, false, $stream_context);
```

Now my question: Is a $stream_context reusable like this:

```
$stream_context = stream_context_create([
    /* some lenghty options array */
]);
read_file('https://'.$host.$uri, false, $stream_context);
get_file_contents($another_url, false, $stream_context);
read_file($even_another, false, $stream_context);
```

or do I need to recreate a new `StreamContext` for each URL ?

Asked differently: **Is a stream context just a descriptor for parameters and options, or does it get bound to the resource when using it ?**

**Edit:** It seems from the comments, that one can reuse `StreamContext` often, but not always. This is not quite satisfactory as an answer.

When can or should it be reused, and when can't it be reused ? Can someone shed some light on the internal working of `StreamContext`. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) looks quite sparse to me.

Comment: You could just try it out. I would expect it to be reusable since it's a resource which is read from but not written to.

Comment: I would say it is its purpose to be reusable; But it seems it might have unexpected results (when not used properly I think) as commented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#117361

Comment: @ilpaijin This point is interesting.

Comment: some context options are domain specific

Comment: What I'm left with as subsidiary question is : does the stream context contain state, like for instance cookies or tls initial negotiation that are passes from one call to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stream contexts are re-usable and they can be re-used always, not often.

The comment from @ilpaijin pointing to "unpredicted behaviour comment" is simple a misunderstanding of the author leaving the comment.

When you specify your context for HTTP wrapper, you specify the wrapper as HTTP regardless of schema you are targeting, meaning there is no such thing as HTTPS wrapper.

If you try to do the following:

```
"https" => [
// options will not be applied to HTTPS stream as there is no such wrapper (https)
]
```

The correct way:

```
"http" => [
// options will apply to http:// and https:// streams.
]
```

**When should/could re-use?**

It's really up to you and up to the logic you are trying to implement.

Don't forget you have default context set for all [native PHP wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php).

The example you have posted where you have the same context stream being passed to 3 different call s is unnecessary, simple use [stream_context_set_default](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php) and set the default context for request originating from your code.

There are certain situations where you set the default but for one particular request you want to have different context, this would be a good idea to create another stream and pass it in.

**Does the stream context contain state, like for instance cookies or tls initial negotiation that are passes from one call to another?**

Stream context does not contain state, however you could achieve a mock like this with additional code. Any state, let it be cookie or TLS handshake, are simply request headers. You would need to read that information from incoming request and set it in the stream, and then pass that stream to other request, thus mocking "the state" of parent request. That being said - don't do it, just use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

On a side, the real power of streams is creating your own/custom [stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php). The header manipulation and state control are much easier (and better) achieved with CURL.

Comment: This is the question that best elaborates the subject. About the critique of http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#117361, I think it misses the point : it is true that `https` is not a wrapper name, `tls` and `ssl` (synonymes) are.

Comment: What I'm left with as subsidiary question is : does the stream context contain state, like for instance cookies or tls initial negotiation that are passes from one call to another?

Comment: Hi Lorenz, thanks for the bounty. I have edited the answer by adding subsidiary question and a tip. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can. I used `xdebug_debug_zval` and ran some simple tests to see if PHP was retaining it internally (I used PHP 7.1.3 with xdebug on an internal development server)

```
$context = stream_context_create(['https' => ['method' => 'GET']]);
xdebug_debug_zval('context');
$stream = file_get_contents('https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php', false, $context);
xdebug_debug_zval('context');
$stream = fopen('https://secure.php.net/', 'r', false, $context);
xdebug_debug_zval('context');
```

What I got back was

> context:
>
> (refcount=1, is_ref=0)resource(2, stream-context)
>
> context:
>
> (refcount=1, is_ref=0)resource(2, stream-context)
>
> context:
>
> (refcount=2, is_ref=0)resource(2, stream-context)

Interestingly, the second call increased the refcount, meaning it was passed by reference internally. Even unsetting `$stream` didn't remove it or prevent me from calling it again.

## Edit

Since the question was modified...

A context creates a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) data type. Because it contains an instance of PHP data, it is passed *by reference implicitly*, meaning that PHP is passing the internal data directly and not simply making a copy of it. There's no native way to destroy a context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it answers strictly the question 'Is a StreamContext reusable', it is not what I expected. In fact, there are cases, where it isn't reusable, like when it involves an SSL connection (see the comments). What I would like to better understand is what is really a StreamContext conceptually. How to grasp it and not just use it.

Comment: Maybe you should share the code for `read_file` then. I can't replicate a case where the stream context can't be reused. The PHP functions pass it *by reference* so it shouldn't ever be destroyed

Answer (score 1):

It apparently serves as a connection object (same logic like with database connection) and can be reused in a similar way:

```
<?php
$default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar",
    'proxy'=>"tcp://10.54.1.39:8000"
  )
);


$alternate_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
              "Content-length: " . strlen("baz=bomb"),
    'content'=>"baz=bomb"
  )
);

$default = stream_context_get_default($default_opts);
$alternate = stream_context_create($alternate_opts);

/* Sends a regular GET request to proxy server at 10.54.1.39
 * For www.example.com using context options specified in $default_opts
 */
readfile('http://www.example.com');

/* Sends a POST request directly to www.example.com
 * Using context options specified in $alternate_opts
 */
readfile('http://www.example.com', false, $alternate);

?>
```

Comment: Note that the question is using `read_file` and not `readfile`. That's not a trivial difference

Comment: Yes indeed... Actually I do not know what is read_file. What I wanted to say is that contexts may be custom and default. And default context can be used behind the scenes multiple times. Also contexts don't need to be closed or recycled. It should mean that they do not collect any state between requests.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with above answers, stream_context_create() will create and return handle to resource by taking option parameters for a connection. This can be re-used to different resources, as it is a handle. Does not matter, where it is used but needs to have handle within the request.